# How to Install Oculus SDK 0.4.4 and run something on DK2

Tags: games, sdk

I am new to Linux altogether, as well as the Oculus Rift.

I have got my DK2 to work on Windows laptop, so I know it is functional.

I just built a new PC and decided to run Ubuntu 14.04 and see how the "rift" works on it. I downloaded the newest Oculus SDK for Linux, 0.4.4, from [here](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/), released a couple weeks ago. My question is probably simple for most of you, what do I do now?

I ran "oculusd" and plugged in my HDMI and it was displaying the desktop, so it is connecting and working but how do I go about playing games? is it automatically in 'extended mode'? The read-me file was little help as I'm sure it's referring to a lot of Linux specifics that I'm unfamiliar with. I noticed the configuration tool doesn't even have a button for the demo (like it does in windows).

Answer (score 3):

The world demo button in RiftConfigUtil will be grayed out initially until a user profile is created.  Click the button labelled '+' and fill out your info first.

Assuming you have an Nvidia card, the easiest way to modify your display settings is with the nvidia-settings program that is installed along with the proprietary nvidia drivers. In order to get full framerate and no "judder", you really need a new/beefy gaming video card.

I have only been able to get 75 hz refresh when setting the rift as another X11 display 'X Screen 1'.  My monitors are only capable of 60Hz which might be limiting framerate when not using two explicit X11 screens. eg, :0.0 and :0.1.  Make sure to leave the Rift in vertical/portrait non-rotated mode for best performance.

You can then run oculusd on the second display via:
DISPLAY=:0.1 ./oculusd

Launch the world demo in the same way after compiling it:
DISPLAY=:0.1 Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release

F9 will then put the Tuscany demo into fullscreen and rotated properly. I hope you get it working.

And now for the bad news... there aren't many games being released for Linux+Oculus currently.  I'm hopeful either Steam or some open source games will start supporting it soon.